# Python: Reading columns and rows from SQLite file into Prettytable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm hoping for some help with Prettytable.  I'm trying to read a file (called "file.db") and draw out a table of interest (called "baseball") and then print the columns within a PrettyTable layout.

I'm struggling with getting the SQL output from the file into a Prettytable.  Any thoughts?

The output below will select the correct file, table in the file, and provides a listing of the data in the relevant rows.  But, my Prettytable isn't working.  My selected data isn’t displayed within it.  All I’m getting is my Prettytable columns that I’m specifying.  :

```
import os 
import sqlite3 
import prettytable

DIR_NAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
db_path = os.path.join(DIR_NAME, "file.db")
print(db_path)

try:
    sqlConn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
except sqlConn.DatabaseError:
    print("I can't open this database")
    exit(0)

print("Database was processed")

db = sqlConn.execute("SELECT * FROM baseball")

myTable = prettytable.from_db_cursor(db)
cursor = sqlConn.cursor()
rows = db.fetchall()
print(rows)

print(myTable.get_string(fields=["bats", "balls", "uniforms"]))
for row in rows:
    myTable.add_row(row)
    print(myTable)
sqlConn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The query result is an iterator; by looping over it to print it, to have exhausted it. Remove that for loop.

Comment: That didn't work.  Plus, I'm thinking that iterating with a for loop is necessary to print all rows of the table...?